# Bitcoin Core 21.1 still no coin for me?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

I have it setup i think on Windows 10 64 bit setup the wallets and encrypted it its been running solid for 8 hours and my bitcoin is showing 0.0000000 BTC still both available and pending what am i missing? In the info screen connections i have 22 (12 in and 10 out) number of transactions is 1078 like am i missing something? do i have to set something in CMD ? I checked the fire wall and allowed 8333 port and allowed the program to run in defender

Comment: You're missing some information. Do you know your wallet had coins in it earlier?

Comment: Does the status bar at the bottom of the window say "Synchronising with network"?

Comment: Are you trying to recover an old wallet, or are you under the impression that just running Bitcoin Core will cause money to be credited? Successful mining with home computers has not been feasible since 2013.